# Modules similar to matplotlib's `Gridspec` and `GridSpecFromSubplotSpec` in pyqtgraph

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, pyqtgraph

I have identified that the most time-consuming step in the execution of code is saving plots to memory. I'm using `matplotlib` for plotting and saving the plots. The issue is that I'm running several simulations and saving the plots resulting from these simulations; this effort is consuming an insane number of compute hours. I have verified that it is indeed the plotting that is doing the damage.

It seems that `pyqtgraph` renders and saves images comparatively faster than `matplotlib.` I want to know if something similar to the following lines of code could be implemented in pyqtgraph?

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 2.5))
rows = 1
columns = 2

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(rows, columns, hspace=0.0,wspace=0.0)
aj=0
for specie in lines:

    for transition in species[specie].items():
        gss = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2, 1, subplot_spec=gs[aj],hspace=0.0,height_ratios=[1, 3])

        ax0 = fig.add_subplot(gss[0])
        ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gss[1], sharex=ax0)
        ax0.plot(fitregs[specie+transition[0]+'_Vel'],fitregs['N_residue'],color='black',linewidth=0.85)                
        ax1.plot(fitregs[specie+transition[0]+'_Vel'],fitregs['N_flux'],color='black',linewidth=0.85)
        ax1.plot(fitregs[specie+transition[0]+'_Vel'],fitregs['Best_profile'],color='red',linewidth=0.85)

        ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator())
        ax1.tick_params(which='both', width=1)
        ax1.tick_params(which='major', length=5)
        ax1.tick_params(which='minor', length=2.5)
        ax1.text(0.70,0.70,r'$\chi^{2}_{\nu}$'+'= {}'.format(round(red_chisqr[aj],2)),transform=ax1.transAxes)
        ax1.text(0.10,0.10,'{}'.format(specie+' '+transition[0]),transform=ax1.transAxes)
        ak=ak+1
        aj=aj+1
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
canvas.print_figure('fits.png')
```

Example output from the above code is [image: example]

Comment: Since your code is not executable (see [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), maybe you could provide a screenshot of the layout you are trying to achieve?

Comment: That being said, the answer is pretty much assuredly "yes". Refer to [the example using GraphicsLayout](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/develop/examples/GraphicsLayout.py). If you cannot get the desired result, then ask a new question with the code you have tried and explain where you are stuck

Comment: @DizietAsahi I have included a screenshot of the layout that I'm trying to achieve, and also reduced the unnecessary clutter in the code.

Comment: @DizietAsahi, thanks for the example using GraphicsLayout. It is, indeed helping me get what I want. I only intend to save the images, so there is no need to have them displayed. How do I prevent the images from being displayed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52250075/1356000

Comment: The above SO posting doesn't have a solution to closing the window. I have figured out a way (gave an answer on the SO post) to export the plot and save it to file, but unable to close the open window automatically.